# AWS - IAM policy for API Gateway

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I am build an API for internal services (no end users), and I would like to secure it.
It is going to be server-to-server communication and there is going to be only one user.

I am trying to create a IAM policy that will block everything but will allow requests with "Authorization:" header.

Is it possible?

This is what I am trying to do:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:Invoke"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:Invoke"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          ///// I can't find the correct condition
          "aws:PrincipalArn": "user"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to restrict access to your API to a user in the account hosting the API, or to a user in a different account?